# MySql (phpmyadmin) JSON Default Value without '

Tags: mysql, json, phpmyadmin, standards

i got the following Problem, I want to set the default value of a Json in a MySql Table to {"test":true,"test2":false}
If i try to put it as the default value in phpmyadmin with type Json it gets changed to '{"test":true,"test2":false}'
I don't want the ' at the beginning and end but I'm not sure how to remove them.

Maybe someone knows how to fix this.

Thank you in advance,
Patrick

Edit:
[New data standard value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M3V6o.png)

Edit 2: [The Upper one is if I use the standard value, the lower one is if my application writes into the Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nYPzM.png)

Comment: Quotes wraps string literal, they are not a part of a value and cannot be removed.

Comment: But in my case it is part of the Value
I added a Screenshot.

Comment: Your screenshot is not server answer, it is client software tale about server answer. Show the same using CLI. And add the column definition from CREATE TABLE which creates this default value (both from your query and got using SHOW CREATE TABLE in CLI).

Comment: @Akina you are right, when I use the CLI to edit the default value it seems to work (it still uses the ' when i insert it with phpmyadmin but when i use a sql query it uses the value without the ')